# NSURL from image works fine but not with certificate file

Tags: cocoa-touch, certificate, nsurl, nsbundle, mainbundle

NSURL *imgPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"mycert" withExtension:@"cer"];

The above code works fine with image or other media resources but returns NULL with .cer file!

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: in swift I have tried its working fine.

Comment: `let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "xyz", ofType: "cer")`
`let path1 = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "xyz", withExtension: "cer")`

I tried both ways and printed in the console.